# What is the meaning of "context" in Spring?

Tags: spring

I was studying about Spring context but then I was wondering what is the meaning of "context" in that and where it's coming from.

I looked up the dictionary but it did not match any of meanings.

I'm not a native speaker so it sounds vague to me or if it is the word that spring team made up then I want to know where it was driven from.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *context* in the Spring Framework is shorthand for `ApplicationContext`, which is the programming construct that the framework uses to access components from the [*Inversion-of-Control* (IoC)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.26/reference/html/core.html#beans) container where they are cached. It is also possible to inject an `ApplicationContext` into a component and to use it to lookup other components (although this is a violation of the inversion of control pattern).

It is possible for an application to have multiple contexts (and therefore multiple or structured caches of components) which in the old XML world usually mapped to having several XML configuration files.

There's a good article below on how the concept of the application context relates to the concept of the bean factory, which produces components from the XML or annotation driven configuration:

- [*Difference Between BeanFactory and ApplicationContext in Spring*](https://dzone.com/articles/difference-between-beanfactory-and-applicationcont)

Linguistically "*context*" is a vague term for the abstract "set of circumstances" in which an event occurs. However in the context of the Spring Framework (see what I did there?), the `ApplicationContext` is well defined and understood by framework users as the state of the IoC container from which a component has been produced via Dependency Injection.